# Firing event when user clicks no matches found jquery plugin select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Is there a possible way to fire an event when user clicks the no matches found message in jquery plugin select2??? i need that event for my project i have tried this code but it seems not working

```
$('.select2-no-results').live('click',function(){
alert("Yes");
});

$('.select2-drop-active').delegate('li.select2-no-results','click',function(){
alert('Hello');
});
```

is there a possible solution for this????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope my solution helps with your problem:

***Select2 configuration**

```
var $select2 = $('#select2_id').select2(
{
    //Your parameters
    formatNoMatches: Not_Found
});
```

***Error handling function**

```
function Not_Found()
{
    var $not_found = '<div>Result not found. <a href="#" onclick="return myClick()">click here to event</a></div>';
    return $not_found;
}
```

***myClick() function**

```
function myClick()
{
  alert('hello');
}
```

Note: In my code, this function needs to be at the top to avoid an error which I don't know why this happens.

Source: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/276

Comment: Is there a way to pass arguments to the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
$('.select2-drop-active').on('click','li.select2-no-results',function(){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

Comment: i have tried this also but its not working but anyways thanks for the effort of answering well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try using .trigger()

```
   $(".select2-no-results").click(function()
                               {
                                  $("li.select2-no-results").trigger("click");
                               });
```

Comment: which event your trying to fire ? is it when when user click on error message ?

Comment: that's what above code does but you could split up into different function $(".select2-no-results").click(function() {
myfunction();
});

Comment: any event won't work i think it has something to do with the plugin that i'm using just a hunch.. i'm currently searching for the solution but anyways thanks for your concern