# How to overwrite a setting in jQuery Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-select2

I've multiple instances of Select2 on my page (one of the wordpress / woocommerce admin pages). For one of the instances I want to overwrite the `language.noResults` function so as to show custom message along with a link (similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22429095/332188). But I don't want to overwrite any other settings that were used while creating the Select2 instance. If I use the code given in above link, it stops the original functionality (AJAX call to fetch matching records).

I've gone through the Select2 documentation @

https://select2.org/

http://select2.github.io/select2/#documentation

But I could not find any way to overwrite only 1 setting (`language.noResults`) of a particular instance without disturbing other settings. Can someone help me how to do it?

**Update:**

Based on the comments from Beaver I tried following code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $select2 = $('#customer_user').data('select2');
    // also tried setting the function to $select2.options.options.language.noResults
    $select2.results.options.options.language.noResults = function(str) {
        alert(str);
        var $not_found = '<div>No matches found. <a href="#" onclick="return myClick()">click here to event</a></div>';
        return $not_found;
    }
    console.log($select2);
});
```

In the console I see my function being referenced properly but it doesn't get called.

Comment: So you are using Select2 version before the 4.0.0?

Comment: @beaver Not really. Its the one that comes with WooCommerce and I can see that the version is 4.0.3.

Comment: So there is no `formatNoMatches` option but the new `language: { noResults: ... }}` , see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/cymtff6a/

Comment: @beaver Ok. Thanks for the clarification. But then how do I change the `language.noResults` of existing instance? I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The example as to instances with different no results setting

Comment: @beaver Yes. I saw that. But there you are creating the instances yourself. In my case the select2 instances are created by WooCommerce plugin. I just need to change the `noResults` function for one of the existing instance that are created by WooCommerce.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that plugin